# Android code to create a translucent view in background on click of my floating action button

Tags: android

This is what I have done so far. Created `FloatingActionButton`. Now I want to set a transparent background layer when I click on the floating button

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
 <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionsMenu
                android:id="@+id/actionMenu"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
                fab:fab_addButtonColorNormal="@color/primary"
                fab:fab_addButtonColorPressed="@color/primary_dark"
                fab:fab_addButtonPlusIconColor="#ffffff">

                <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:onClick="openAudio"
                    fab:fab_colorNormal="#EA1E63"
                    fab:fab_colorPressed="#EA1E63"
                    fab:fab_icon="@drawable/ic_action_mic" />

                <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:onClick="openAttachment"
                    fab:fab_colorNormal="#89C440"
                    fab:fab_colorPressed="#89C440"
                    fab:fab_icon="@drawable/ic_action_attachment" />

                <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:onClick="openCamera"
                    fab:fab_colorNormal="#FE5722"
                    fab:fab_colorPressed="#FE5722"
                    fab:fab_icon="@drawable/ic_action_camera" />

            </com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionsMenu>

</RelativeLayout
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make onclick method of floating action button in your java code.

```
 public void openAudio(View v)
        {
        //Make parent relative layout to be translucent
findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#80000000"));
        }
```

Comment: I want to get a transparent view with the first floating action button (plus icon)